# AutoHotKey SetKeyDelay option does not appear to work

Tags: autohotkey

I have a very simple AutoHotKey script which I wish to introduce a visible delay between the characters typed ...I have read the documentation on SetKeyDelay but the example below does not seem to provide any key delay ...any thoughts ? I would expect that when I type **rpa** and the hit **enter** key, the characters would type *slowly* ...more like a human typing.

```
SetKeyDelay ,3000,200

::rpa::
Send {Text} 
(

while ( iterator?.hasNext() ) {
    def comp = iterator.next()
    if (comp.sku != null ) {
        def row = [
                "sku"         : comp.sku,
                "ProductGroup": comp.attribute1,
                "BusinessUnit": comp.attribute2
        ]
    }
}

)

return
```

Answer (score 0):

*When a new script is created the **SendMode Input;** line is automatically inserted*.

**Remove the `SendMode Input;` fixed the issue.**